# Blackburn Central bike Rack

Tags: rack

I'm trying to mount a blackburn central rear bike rack on my Kona Dew bike. I'm on step two of the four step instructions and cannot seem to fit the extender rod through the cam lock when the cam lock is on the post of the rack as instructed. Has anyone else dealt with this problem and have a solution?

---

[image: From https://www.blackburndesign.com/p/central-rear-bike-rack]
From https://www.blackburndesign.com/p/central-rear-bike-rack

Comment: At the moment, unless someone happens to have a copy of the instructions in front of them, we're highly unlikely to be able to help. Maybe you could track down a copy online, or post a photo of the relevant section and the trouble you're having

Comment: And photos of your bike and rack showing the issue you are having

Comment: This seems like a good question, but we're lacking details.  Can you photograph the instructions and your bike, wiht the rack in place?  Use [edit] to add them to your question.

Comment: Also, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYRWNm7uUYU  shows installation of a different model, but does have a Cam lock.  Does that match your rack?

Comment: There are many, many different pannier racks in the world. At the moment, your question can only be answered by somebody who is very familiar with this specific model and, honestly, it's very unlikely that somebody with exactly the right knowledge will stumble on this question. Please, help us to help you. Anybody who works with bikes should be able to help you, if only you provide enough information. Please include a copy of the instructions you're trying to follow, photographs of the relevant parts, photographs of the partial installation on your bike. Anything that might help.